# jqGrid - customize modal popup

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to customize the modal pop-up for edit in jqGrid?
I have this situation : 
A grid with customer info showing street, postal code, city, country...
In my db a customer has much more properties than these : vat number, representative, telephone,...

I would like to show this additional info when you click "edit"

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Has this question been answered? I have the same problem right now

Answer (score 0):

```
        {
            name:'id_calificacion',
            index:'id_calificacion', 
            width:100,
            hidden: true,//oculta el campo en el grid
            sortable:false,
            editable:true
            editrules:{edithidden:true}//this option show the fiels in edit mode
        },
```